# Does tomcat support http PATCH method?

Tags: tomcat, httprequest, restful-architecture

A PATCH request to tomcat returns "HTTP Status 501 - Method PATCH is not is not implemented by this servlet for this URI" error. Is it possible to allow the PATCH method in tomcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar question was answered here: [How do I stop Apache httpd from rejecting HTTP PATCH requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994833/how-do-i-stop-apache-httpd-from-rejecting-http-patch-requests/15621131#15621131?newreg=8eb1205cba8c4e20be16e1fe18afc799)

Tested on Tomcat 7 - the request does go through, unless you have Apache in front connected via AJP13.

AJP 13 does not yet support PATCH, all supported methods are here:http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/ajp/ajpv13a.html under "method" section.

Comment: The AJP protocol supports PATCH. This is documented in [this bug report here](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56884). However, mod_proxy may not support PATCH over AJP.