# How to mock a 501 error from ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, http

I've got an http 501 error bubbling up in prod from this call:

```
return $.ajax({
    url: finalUrl,
    success: function (result) {
        console.log('success call result');
        console.log(result);
        finalResult = result;
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    type: 'PATCH',
    contentType: 'application/json'
});
```

How can I return a mock simulating the error so I can test a fix outside of production?  I looked at the response tab in chrome and I see an HTML message:

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Unsupported Request</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Unsupported Request</H1>
PATCH to http&#58;&#47;&#47;demo&#46;site&#46;com&#47;serviceName&#47;v1&#47;requests&#47;9305e338&#45;666a&#45;e611&#45;8516&#45;000c291891bb not supported.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;8&#46;f0fd717&#46;1472154919&#46;9959c96
</BODY></HTML>
```

We suspect that the API is not being hit at all, blocked by a firewall. I don't know if I should expect a string or object in this case?  If object, then what are the members of that object?

Fiddler says:

Server: AkamaiGHost 
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 350
Expires: Thu, 25 Aug 2016 20:21:49 GMT
Date: Thu, 25 Aug 2016 20:21:49 GMT
Connection: close

Comment: My suggestion would be to use [Mockjax](https://github.com/jakerella/jquery-mockjax) - at allows you to capture any AJAX request and craft a custom response.

Comment: Is there an HTTP code returned like, perhaps, 405 or 501?  Otherwise you're left handling the raw HTML.  **EDIT** too dumb to read today I guess.  Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

> We suspect that the API is not being hit at all, blocked by a firewall.

From the error, it looks like you're hitting a back-end that isn't configured for that request-type.

See these questions for a potential solution, assuming you control the back-end too.

[Does tomcat support http PATCH method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805957/does-tomcat-support-http-patch-method)

[How do I stop Apache httpd from rejecting HTTP PATCH requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994833/how-do-i-stop-apache-httpd-from-rejecting-http-patch-requests/15621131#15621131?newreg=8eb1205cba8c4e20be16e1fe18afc799)

If you do control the back-end, but the above doesn't help, make sure that your controller function supports that request method.  In Spring, for example, you have to declare that explicitly:

```
@Controller
MyController {

   @Requestmapping(value = "/api/patchTheThing", method=RequestMethod.PATCH)
   @ResponseBody String patchTheThing(....) {
        ...
   }
}
```

Comment: We do control the backend.  The issue only occurs in production.  It does not happen in lower environments.  That's why we think this is server/firewall related.

Comment: Is the server architecture the same between dev and prod environments?  E.g. do you connect directly to tomcat over port 8080 locally, but use apache + mod_proxy to connect over port 80/443 in production?  If so, it's possible the answers linked above could help.

Answer (score 0):

Just set up an endpoint on a server of your choice and use your web server configure or coding language of your choice to issue a 501 response. But the problem seems pretty clear, the server is not expecting a PATCH request. If you had some networking problem you would not be getting a response at all.

you should strongly consider making sure your JavaScript code handles both happy path / success outcome as well as other types off sever response outcomes so your application can better handle how it wants to recover from such errors.

Comment: We make PATCH requests to this API just fine.  It's only under a very narrow circustance:  In Prod and for people not on the VPN that this issue kicks up.

Comment: Are people not on VPN not having having request proxied through or redirected to a different endpoint which does not support PATCH?

Comment: They are proxied through yes. They use something called AkamaiGHost . I can't tell you what else is happening.  The request should eventually make it down to our same API.  That's all I know.

Comment: Looks like you need to look at the request/response details to see where this response is coming from if not your app server.